# Multiple Indexes for collection - Only one works

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

First off, I'm kind of new to Firebase Database and coming from a SQL background.

I'm attempting to have a query that returns all notifications for a specified `postID`, regardless of which user the notification is for.

Essentially, if somebody deletes their post, I want to delete all of the "new post" notifications sent to all of their followers.

My data structure
[image]

I've tried these indexes..

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "notification": {
      "$user_id": {
            ".indexOn": ["timestamp", "objectId"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can query by `timestamp` with the following code, and it works fine.

```
 dbRef.GetChild("notificaton").GetChild(userID).GetQueryOrderedByChild("timestamp");
```

However, I don't want to use the `userID` in my query for post notifications. I've searched and tried a couple of other configurations for an index, but I just get errors in the firebase db admin that there are issues with my indexes.

I believe this is because I do need to query by `timestamp`, so that index needs to stay. So I need two indexes for the same collection, but different configurations because of `user_id` not being needed for the `postID` index.

I'm not sure how the index needs to be configured to be able to query on `objectId` regardless of `user_id`.

I've also tried something like this..

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "notification": {
        ".indexOn": ["objectId"]
    },
    "notification": {
      "$user_id": {
        ".indexOn": ["timestamp"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I get an error `Error saving rules: 'notification' occurs multiple times.`

I've tried this..

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "notification": {
      "$user_id": {
        ".indexOn": ["timestamp"]
      },
      ".indexOn": ["objectId"]
    }
  }
}
```

And Firebase seems OK with that, as it doesn't give an error, but it also doesn't return any data, which I assume is because `objectId` is not on the root `notification` collection.

So I'm stuck.

Comment: Can you tag your question with the language/platform you're coding on? That will at the very least highlight the code in your question, but frequently also allows us to better help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add indexes to each user of both the `timestamp` and the `objectId` of each of their child nodes, you can do so with:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "notification": {
      "$user_id": {
        ".indexOn": ["objectId", "timestamp"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This allows you to query a user for child nodes with a matching objectId, or query a user for child nodes based on the timestamp.

---

Firebase queries always return direct child nodes of the location you run them on. That means that the `orderByChild()` clause of a query must refer to a fixed path to a single property of each direct child node. In other words: you cannot query a tree.

In your case that means that you cannot search across the notifications of all users with a single query. If you want to allow that query, you'll need to store a list of notifications for all users.